# Mysql select from columns with same value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

We have a hotel booking table with data as following

```
id  room  night        bookingid  timestamp
 1    1    2018-05-01   18         2018-04-07 01:34:41
 2    1    2018-05-02   18         2018-04-07 01:34:41
 3    1    2018-05-05   19         2018-04-07 01:34:40
 4    1    2018-05-06   19         2018-04-07 01:34:40
 5    2    2018-05-01   20         2018-04-07 01:34:39
 6    2    2018-05-02   20         2018-04-07 01:34:39
 7    2    2018-05-03   21         2018-04-07 01:34:37
 8    2    2018-05-04   21         2018-04-07 01:34:37
```

What we need to achieve is to select value from results with same bookingid

example:
select * from table where nights > 2018-05-01 and bookingid is the same ....
if there is result this should show : Yes else echo no.
so in this case should echo as yes

OR:
select * from table where nights > 2018-05-02 and bookingid is the same ....
if there is result this should show : Yes else echo no.
so this should echo as NO

how can you do that?

Comment: I don't think so, because the only way to achieve it, is by filtering by a specific `ID`

Comment: Sample data and desired results always help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what did you mean? she should filter by `ID` if she needs the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.bookingid in (select t2.bookingid from table t2 where t2.night > '2018-05-02');
```

It is not clear from your question if you want to limit the results in the outer query based on the condition in the subquery.  If so, just repeat the `where` condition in the outer query.